# Campanha: Postar comentários ao dar votos negativos ou de fechamento. Vença o desgate de fazer isso!

Tags: debate, voto-contra, perguntas-fechadas, novos-usuários

## O problema que temos hoje

Recentemente, nos últimos 2 ou 3 dias, vi pelo menos uns 5 usuários novatos diferentes reclamando de que o SOpt não está amigável, que fecharam a pergunta sem maiores explicações e com todas aquelas reclamações já típicas de novatos.

Entendo perfeitamente que grande parte das perguntas feitas por novatos são muito ruins, que muitas vezes não dá nem para saber qual que é o assunto da pergunta de tão mal elaborada que ela é. Outras vezes são coisas apenas off-topic ou com outros tipos de problemas recorrentes. Logo, temos votos negativos e fechamentos.

Da parte dos usuários experientes, vejo bastante desânimo e desmotivação em conversar e explicar a usuários novatos como funciona o site, pois isso é algo muito desgastante e inglório, pois são poucos os novatos que entendem a mensagem e melhoram posteriormente, sendo que a maioria apenas reage com ataques contra quem postou o comentário. Isso também demanda um tempo precioso que poderia ser gasto de outra forma e que muitas vezes parece ser jogar pérolas aos porcos.

E também, as razões de fechamento existentes (com exceção talvez do "não está em português" e o caso de duplicatas) acabam sendo genéricas demais para que os novatos possam entender exatamente o que há de errado na pergunta deles. Então, em muitos casos, a razão de fechamento escolhida dentre as opções dadas não basta para instruir os novatos.

## A solução

A situação como dá, não funciona. Se quisermos fazer bom uso deste site, precisamos tomar alguma atitude. Se conseguirmos conscientizar 5% dos novatos que entram aqui, acredito que as coisas já melhorariam visivelmente. Portanto, **a minha proposta é que todos que form dar um voto negativo ou de fechamento, que postem algum comentário explicando ao autor da pergunta ou resposta em questão o porquê do voto negativo ou de fechamento.** Sei que é algo bastante desgastante, desmotivador, chato e entediante, mas não consigo vislumbrar outra forma de fazer com que este site melhore pelo menos um pouco. Adotando esta postura, teremos menos pessoas se frustrando por aqui por não entender como as coisas funcionam. Ou ao menos será mais fácil na hora de fechar uma pergunta, dar o link de alguma outra que teve um problema de elaboração semelhante.

E se você não consegue dar uma justificativa para o fato de estar votando negativamente ou para o fechamento, talvez isso seja um sinal de que você não deveria estar votando assim. Embora o que eu vejo é que a maioria dos votos negativos e de fechamento são perfeitamente justificáveis, é apenas por falta de ânimo mesmo que os comentários pertinentes não são dados. Respire fundo e tire um minuto para escrever aquele comentário.

Se o usuário novato em questão quiser entram numa discussão ou num debate que não vale a pena participar com quem deu o voto negativo e/ou de fechamento, ninguém é obrigado a responder. Se o usuário novato responder com grosseria ou ameaça, toma uma sinalização. Se você já deu a sua justificativa e não tem estômago para continuar a falar disso, ninguém vai te obrigar.

Talvez caiba também uma mudança de mentalidade. Deixar um voto negativo ou de fechamento sem maiores explicações, vai deixar um usuário novato frustrado e confuso. Mas se você postou um comentário, poderá ficar mais tranquilo de que fez a sua parte e cabe a quem recebeu o comentário absorver ou não aquilo. E se em 1000 vezes que você fizer isso, houver 20 novatos que entenderão e então vierem a se tornar bons usuários veteranos, então esse esforço já terá valido a pena, mesmo se os demais 980 não reagirem bem.

Às vezes, eu vou mais longe e posto comentários em perguntas e respostas que foram negativadas e/ou fechadas por outras pessoas, para que o usuário não fique sem explicação.

Para demonstrar, eis alguns exemplos de comentários que deixei por aí:

> Sinto cheiro de [injeção de SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL) e de [XSS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). E também não consigo entender como isto supostamente responde ao que foi perguntado.

> Não entendi o que você está pedindo. Você nem sequer mencionou qual é a linguagem de programação ou programa no qual você tem essas tabelas. Você não disse quais são as funções e loops que tentou. E também não explicou nada sobre o significado dessas variáveis que você tem. Fica difícil assim.

> O StackOverflow tem uma forma de funcionamento que é bem diferente de outros sites mesmo, e isso sempre gerou muito atrito. Até se acostumar em como as coisas funcionam é algo um tanto difícil mesmo. O que acontece é que perguntas excessivamente abertas e com poucos detalhes dificilmente têm informações suficientes para que possam ser respondidas com alguma resposta razoável, por isso elas são fechadas. Mas isso é algo simples de resolver, basta se esforçar um pouquinho na redação da pergunta e tentar colocar nelas todas as informações necessárias, e a pergunta será aceita.

> Sem ter maiores detalhes sobre o seu código (inclusive o `pom.xml`), fica difícil te apontar um caminho.

> Onde aparece o erro 500? É no `utilizacao_peca = UtilizacaoPeca.objects.get(pk=pk)`? Se for, edite a pergunta e adicione o código da classe `UtilizacaoPeca`.

> Desculpe-me fechar a sua pergunta, mas isso é mais um caso de usar `==` ao invés de `equals`.

Comment: Quem tiver resposta sobre o tema, poste no campo apropriado para que a comunidade possa votar. Ou use o link do chat pra prosseguir ou consultar a conversa (que continua aberta no lugar apropriado): https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106710/

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/159549/meaness-of-site para dar um parâmetro.

Comment: @Maniero não sei se é possivel, mas uma filtragem de perguntas fechadas com comentários que incluem o link para o "Guia de sobrevivência"

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento possível sempre é, é só alguém fazer, essa daria um bom trabalho :)

Comment: Eu não manjo muito do SEDE, então essa query que fiz não deve estar 100%:  https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/1226359/search-comments-by-comment-text

Comment: Como virou nova discussão, bloqueei os comentários permanentemente. Queiram usar o link do chat acima.

Answer (score 6):

Um dos meus medos é que algumas pessoas vão interpretar isso como "não feche ou negative algo se não for comentar. Isso não é solução, é aumento do problema real. Se for para a pessoa estabelecer que só vai fechar ou negativar algo se negativar, então comente muito.

E quero dizer que a maior frustração que que boa parte dessas pessoas vão ter são causadas por elas mesmas, e elas terão muitas na vida, porque embora em parte seja um problema, o fato delas não conhecerem o site não é o problemas delas, elas costumam ter um comportamento que sempre causarão problemas. As que não se frustram o suficiente estão mais preparadas pra vida e vão contribuir melhor para a comunidade.

Eu me frustrei bastante no começo do site, todas minhas postagens não existem mais. Mas eu segui em frente ,eu via valor nisso mesmo tendo sido tratado como um idiota, talvez pelo meu inglês ser deficiente. Fiz uma limonada.

## É bom comentar

Eu acho interessante que as pessoas cometem e ajudem, sempre disse isso e apoio a iniciativa.

Eu acho que existe um problema muito pior e acho que comentários não estão adiantando. Eu estou sempre aqui, eu participo de quase tudo e vejo que não adianta.

Ainda assim quem quiser gastar seu tempo acho bom fazê-lo. E eu sei que gasta tempo. Se a pessoa acha que não gasta, então ótimo para ela. meu relógio funciona diferente.

Haverá desgaste e frustração. Isso não é fácil também. Para quem participa um pouco do site, quem vem e vai pode não sentir tanto, eu sinto e vejo que muita gente sente.

## A comunidade não faz sua parte

Pra mim complica um pouco mais porque tenho que tomar decisões difíceis o tempo todo. Porque eu sei que a solução não é fugir dessas decisões. Nem sempre posso decidir sobre tudo, mas sou "obrigado". Eu disse que atuaria na moderação quando a comunidade falhasse, e pouco a pouco ela foi falhando cada vez mais. Hoje é comum as pessoas decidirem não tomar uma ação no site mesmo sabendo que precisa que uma pergunta é ruim. Sobre pra mim. E para outras pessoas, vou destacar o Bacco, mas tem várias.

Com o volume de coisas que tem para fazer porque algumas pessoas não fazem, é complicado fazer mais. Eu não consegui fazer mais que isso. Por isso quem puder fazer mais terá minha gratidão (se é que isso vale pra alguma coisa).

Se eu tivesse que analisar menos coisas porque eu sei que a comunidade está avaliando bem eu poderia me concentrar mais em algumas e fazer um trabalho melhor.

## Qualidade

Mas eu não acho que a solução é deixar pra lá porque eu não tenho tempo. A gente vê que há mais mal quando se deixa pra lá do que bem. E o pior é algumas pessoas acharem que não há mal, o que mostra que o mal invisível tem popularidade. Eu prefiro não ser populista, prefiro o certo.

## Ineficácia

Quando eu consigo comentar costuma ser ineficaz. Quase sempre. Acontece com outras pessoas.

Muitas vezes a pessoa não está nem aí, ela não quer saber de nada, não liga para o site, não liga para outras pessoas, não liga nem pro seu próprio aprendizado. Ela só quer ver algo na frente dela. É uma tragédia de dimensões que eu nunca imaginei que veria.

Outras vezes a capacidade dela de comunicação, de interpretar texto, de entender sobre o que se trata ali, o que fazer, de seguir instruções, de tomar uma decisão, de agir para algo evoluir, é tão limitada que não tem o que fazer.

Você tem tempo de ser babá das pessoas? Eu não tenho. Mas fique à vontade se tiver.

## Motivador

E claro que não é só questão de tempo, é de motivação, você acha tempo quando está motivado. Mas que motivação me dá em tentar ajudar alguém que começou muito mal, ela não cometeu um pequeno erro, ela foi completamente displicente? Considerando ainda que o resultado não dá resultado bom em quase 100% dos casos. As pessoas que se salvam não costumam dar trabalho.

Eu não ganho qualquer coisa para estar aqui, eu preciso ter alguma motivação, e consigo alguma, consigo por exemplo ainda querer "fazer da internet um lugar melhor", lembram disso? Eu ainda acredito que pode-se fazer um site com material de qualidade, e para isso é necessário extirpar o conteúdo de má qualidade. Por que precisa ter conteúdo ruim? Por que vamos incentivar isso?

Repito que não sou contra comentário, mas como disse o hkotsubo, em geral só está cuidando do sintoma, não está resolvendo a causa. È mais um motivo para eu não me motivar a comentar. O que não quer dizer que eu não comente aqui ou ali, quando me sinto motivo por uma razão ou outra.

Mas o fato de saber que tem uma chance razoável de ser ignorado ou desrespeitado, quando não for agredido, me desmotiva bastante.

O que tem nessa proposta de campanha que faz me dar motivação? Eu estou esperando por isso, se conseguirem me dar essa motivação poderá acontecer naturalmente, e é assim que tem que ser, deve ser natural.

Por isso que muitos vem aqui pedem pra fazer algo e não fazem, elas só conseguiram motivação para reclamar, não para fazer a parte dela. Novamente, é fácil fazer por um tempo, e talvez seja fácil para algum que tem bastante tempo ou tem uma personalidade mais afeita para esse tipo de atividade.

De fato a "Pergunta" é duplicata porque ela não acrescenta nada novo, não é algo que surgiu agora que, diferente das outras vezes, tem uma sacada sensacional e agora as pessoas se sentirão compelidas a realizar isso.

Eu até gostaria que alguém conseguisse criar essa motivação.

## Tempos difíceis

Eu nunca achei que dar esmola para alguém ajudasse em alguma coisa, a não ser que você incentivava mais ainda ter pessoas pedindo esmola.

Eu prefiro oferecer emprego para as pessoas (mantendo a analogia do parágrafo anterior). Emprego as pessoas não querem, porque ele exige um certo comportamento, exige comprometimento.

Nós vivemos uma época complicada onde o erro e a mediocridade é incentivada, a gente tem que lutar em todo canto contra o achismo se sobrepondo ao correto e comprovado.

## Falta UX

Eu acho que a SE não tem feito um bom trabalho para isso. Assim como o Facebook que hoje muitos sabem manipula as pessoas para produzirem conteúdo para que elas tenham audiência, a SE manda mensagens dúbias, já que o discurso é de qualidade e gratidão pelo esforço das pessoas, mas a ação é de incentivar o conteúdo ruim e dificultar que o conteúdo seja adequadamente moderado com facilidade.

Somos programadores, nós automatizamos nossas tarefas repetitivas. A SE não faz nada para simplificar nosso trabalho e padronizar as ações, dando uma chance maior para quem não for muito aloprado. Algumas pessoas não tem salvação não importa que ferramentas existam, por isso o *link* postado em comentário para o metão com ideias para ajudar no processo é uma boa, mas é um pouco tarde para ter um resultado tão efetivo.

Então pra falar a verdade, mesmo que eu tenha motivação, eu não sei se filosoficamente eu deveria fazer um trabalho braçal maçante que praticamente não dá resultado e que deveria ser desnecessário. Essa é uma questão aberta pra mim.

O que não é aberta é a questão da qualidade. Eu estou cansando tanto que eu posso desistir de moderar, isto está em aberto, mas se eu abrir mão da qualidade e desistir de moderar no sentido de coibir tanto conteúdo ruim, provavelmente eu não resisto no site. E não gostaria de fazer isso depois de investir tanto tempo.

Tem muita coisa ruim que acontece porque a SE não quer ouvir quem usa. Preciso desenhar?

[image: Diferença entre o caminho que desenharam e o que as pessoas usam]

Se a ferramenta não atende as necessidades as pessoas contornam mesmo que cause problemas.

Já falamos bastante aqui sobre isso, no metão tá cheio de pedidos para melhorar, o dia que eles quiseram nos ouvir já tem conteúdo, mas podemos organizar tudo de novo, basta eles mostrarem que é sério que vão fazer o que precisa (eles perderam a confiança da comunidade, então será um pouco mais complicado pedir novos esforços mais um vez nos últimos anos), eu ainda ajudaria porque eu vejo ganho (se eles fizerem mesmo).

Se a SE não liga pra isso porque eu vou ligar para a frustração e confusão de pessoas que não ligam para nada do site que só chegam para sugar e não produzem nada útil? O que eu ganho com isso? O que a comunidade ganha? Quantidade?

## Inversão de valores

Um outro ponto é que eu ainda não consegui entender, e espero que um dia algum especializado em psicologia consiga me explicar, porque as pessoas que precisam de ajuda são sempre priorizadas em relação às pessoas que podem fornecer a ajuda. Isso é o oposto da lei da oferta e da procura.

O único pagamento que as pessoas recebem por ajudar aqui é o respeito. E postar perguntas sem o menor esforço é um desrespeito ao tempo das pessoas. Esse tempo deveria estar sendo usado para ensinar sobre programação e não a como escrever, como usar o computador. como clicar em um *link* e ler regras.

Eu me sinto usado da pior forma possível. Não por todos, é por estes que eu ainda estou aqui.

É justo ser tratado como lixo? É justo incentivar isso? As pessoas acham que estão fazendo um favor para nós quando fazem uma pergunta. Não sei se acompanha tudo o que acontece, até porque muita coisa é apagada. E não estou falando só de ser mal tratado, falo até da pessoa não querer gastar tempo algum para melhorar e deixar que nós precisemos nos esforçar para agradá-lo.

Eu sei que algumas pessoas não conseguem fazer melhor do que fazem, mas eu não sei o que elas estão tentando fazer uma das coisas mais complicadas para um ser humano que é programar. Eu lamento por essas pessoas, mas eu não tenho uma solução.

Assim como dizer para as pessoas passarem comentar **não é uma solução** é uma vontade. Ainda vou esperar pela solução. A "solução" é no mínimo ingênua, o que não é típico do AP e cheio de falácias ou erros grosseiros mesmo.

Quando se propõe algo precisa mostrar que haverá alguma vantagem para a pessoa, para a comunidade, para alguém que a gente se importe. Não vi isso acontecendo.

## Encerramento e conclusão

Se não ficou claro eu não gosto da defesa de que usuários descomprometidos com eles próprios, além da comunidade e com o respeito aos outros devam receber tratamento especial porque quem sabe eles podem se tornar úteis um dia. A experiência é que provavelmente isso aconteça em 0,1% dos casos. As pessoas que se dão bem não precisam de nada especial, só de ajuda para aprender programar ou melhorar em algum ponto.

Eu nem ia escrever algo (se fosse alguém menos comprometido provavelmente não faria) porque eu sei que não leva a lugar algum, as pessoas que são contra isso não mudarão de ideia e eu não mudarei de ideia até que apresentem algo convincente. E eu terei que responder um monte de comentário depois. Sem falar que alguém virá aqui dizer que eu estou fazendo algo negativo, que estou sendo arrogante, ou coisa do tipo. Eu preferi nem entrar tanto em pontos específicos que discordo porque vai longe, já gastei tempo de demais com isso eu preferia achar uma boa pergunta para eu responder.

E quero deixar claro para novatos e quem flutua no site que eu, e acho que a comunidade, estamos mais rígidos do que no passado, porque o nível de ruído se tornou sufocante perto do sinal, algo precisa ser feito que antes não precisava. Ajuda o fato de raramente ter boas respostas.

Agradeço aos que puderem comentar nas perguntas, mais ainda se puderem salvar algo (que a gente sabe que é raro ter um caso assim) e ainda acho que o melhor que pode fazer é não deixar de fechar e negativar o que é ruim, assim a modwração pode ter tempo para comentar mais.

## Atualização

Mais de 30 dias depois as pessoas que publicamente apoiaram a ideia (a discussão teve quase 100 comentários) praticamente não usam o site, não fazem o que pregaram e não ajudaram algo acontecer nesse sentido, então fica claro que era apenas mais um pedido para os outros fazerem o que elas desejam, ou como tem a frase popular "dar esmola com a carteira dos outros". Foi só mais um desgaste.

Comment: Tem um problema bastante prevalente que a UX que faz de conta que não há problemas causa que só moderador percebe, embora não tanto quanto o que está sendo discutido aqui, é problema mais sério. A única solução viável, e mesmo assim parcial, é a UX melhorar considerando que há problemas. A ideia de que "O usuário tem que fazer certo" não é sustentável.

Comment: Na minha opinião, o site está melhor agora, graças a si e outros moderadores bem ativos a fechar o que merece ser fechado no site. Tenho menos perguntas para responder quando quero responder mas sei que não perco tempo a abrir perguntas sem salvação, e apenas me foco em perguntas que valem a pena. E por isso agradeço a quem faz esse trabalho pelo bem da comunidade, gastando-o seu tempo precioso. 
Agora vale lembrar que isso vai contra os ideais da nossa amiga SE, e por isso não sei se eles vão olhar a tudo isto com bons olhos. No final do dia eles querem é quantidade e tudo aberto (...)

Comment: (...) Vamos a ver se no futuro não vão querer entrar aqui de rompante e mudar tudo quanto é regra, para funcionar exatamente da forma que eles querem.

Comment: @Isac os ideais atuais, né? Porque o início da empresa a qualidade era preferida e foi o que atraiu muita gente para participar. A mudança foi o que fez muita gente ir embora, mas agora tem um massa que isso não importa mais. E hoje mesmo em inglês boa parte do conteúdo novo é ruim, e não falo só das perguntas, muita gente não entende quando falamos de quantidade (é material que pode ter até alguma utilidade, mas não é que provoca evolução). E tem coisa que talvez valha a pena de tentar salvar, mas é raro e não sabemos quais. Obrigado. Farei um "fechamento" do assunto aqui em alguns dias.

Comment: Pra ficar perfeito esse edit só faltou encerrar com "conforme previsto." :D

Comment: Esse comportamento bater no peito e gritar nos comentários que todo mundo está errado e depois não fazer nada é obvio, se o usuário quer mudança parte dele mesmo a iniciativa de mudar a própria atitude e se a conduta for boa os outros o seguem, se não for ou passa batido ou alguém orienta. Agora falar que "ain, não faço isso por que outro não fazem" é demagogia.

Comment: @Bacco https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDuIN.png :)