# Alteração do texto do motivo de fechamento "Essa pergunta não parece ser sobre programação, dentro do escopo definido na central de ajuda."

Tags: debate, razões-fechamento

Suponho que, com a existência do "novo" motivo de fechamento: *"Apesar de ser sobre programação..."*, o outro: *"Essa pergunta não parece ser sobre programação, dentro do escopo definido na central de ajuda."*, deverá ser usado quando a pergunta, de todo, não é sobre programação.

No entanto, o trecho *"dentro do escopo definido na central de ajuda."* parece sugerir(pelo uso da virgula) que este motivo pode ser usado quando a pergunta não cumpre o *"definido na central de ajuda."*. Ou seja, pode ser usado numa pergunta sobre programação quando esta não cumpre o definido na central de ajuda.

Esta interpretação faz com que os dois motivos se sobreponham, criando ambiguidade, o que, por vezes, (me) dificulta a escolha de um deles.

Como exemplo, veja a pergunta [C# TCP cliente servidor assincrono](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/447070/2541).

O tema é programação, mas é um pedido de exemplos e textos sobre o assunto o que não está *"dentro do escopo definido na central de ajuda."*

Eu votei para fechar usando o primeiro motivo, outro usuário usou o segundo.
Não vejo que isso seja problema. A pergunta foi fechada, isso é que é o importante.

A escolha do motivo do meu voto, neste caso, foi propositado. Sabendo que ela seria fechada com o outro motivo, permitiria ter um exemplo para trazer o assunto aqui.

Se a minha interpretação da existência dos dois motivos é a correcta, penso que o texto poderia ser melhorado de forma a eliminar a ambiguidade.

Sugestões:

- Essa pergunta não é sobre programação.
- Este é um site de perguntas e respostas sobre programação.
  Essa pergunta não é sobre programação.

Se o texto actual fosse um dos anteriores eu tinha usado, sem hesitações, o motivo *"Apesar de ser sobre programação..."*

Comment: Esse é um problema conhecido, o complicado é que uma vez criado, o motivo não pode ser editado (suponho que para não comprometer os fechamentos anteriores), então ao se criar um novo precisaria de um belo trabalho em cima disso (inclusive esse foi criado antes do Guia, se dependesse só de mim eu desativaria o nosso "custom" atual ("apesar de...") e faria um fechamento que deixasse claro que nao somos helpdesk nem site de ajuda, e sim um repositório de conhecimento, com link destacado para o Guia de Sobrevivência (realçando essa sua questão de "não basta ser sobre programação").

Comment: Você quer mudar o texto do motivo original, né? Não sei até que ponto a SE aceita isso porque eles pensaram bastante no texto. O que ficou acordado é que esse motivo ficaria para casos que claramente não é programação, ou seja, é TI, mas não programação, ou nem TI é, é administração, legislação, matemática, trabalho, biologia (sim vez ou outra aprece coisas assim). Tem funcionado bem assim, não vejo muito o pessoal, até "novato" cometer esse tipo de erro, vejo erros em outras coisas, e muitos.

Comment: E eu usei muito esse primeiro de fora de escopo para perguntas de programação de fato, quando não é objetiva, pontual etc como está na [pagina do escopo](/help/on-topic). Inclusive reposto a frase "dentro do escopo definido na central de ajuda" quando questionam que "é sim de programação".

Comment: Alguns casos realmente complica bastante e eu mesmo fico na dúvida de qual motivo escolher, mas nunca entre esses dois, Mas uma mudança pode ajudar, não estou me opondo não, se o pessoal concordar e a SE resolver que pode mudar, a gente muda, tem que mexer no texto traduzido e pedir para eles trocarem no sistema. Eles andaram simplificando as mensagens o que tornaou-as bastante inexpressivas, ambíguas e gerou mais confusão entre os usuários. Não servem muito mais para orientar.

Comment: @Maniero Eu acredito que o 1o seja caso de pedir um edit de forma a não mudar o teor, só melhorar a escrita. O segundo eu achava ótimo quando não tinha o guia, hoje eu refaria completamente, deixando claro o aspecto "não helpdesk" e "não individual" antes de qq coisa, apontando para o Guia

Comment: Falo disso em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8296/101. Em vez do sistema ajudar na orientação está se valendo dos usuários do site, que há tempos demonstram que não querem fazer isso, inclusive depois daquela postagem não se viu melhora nisso, nem entre as pessoas que a apoiaram. O sistema deve fazer o grosso do trabalho de orientação.

Comment: @Bacco, não sabia dessa dificuldade.

Comment: @ramaral ela não invalida sua colocação. É um complicador, mas é questão de acharmos solução. Deixar errado pq é complicado não combina com programador né :D

Comment: @Maniero, não acho que a ambiguidade seja um grande problema. Há de facto outros piores. Sugeri porque pensava que fosse fácil alterar.