# Como entender porque minhas perguntas recebem votos negativos

Tags: debate

gostaria do auxilio de vocês para compreender o motivo de algumas perguntas serem negativadas sem motivo aparente, perguntas tanto minhas quanto de outros colegas. Busco essa compreensão para que eu possa melhorar a qualidade das perguntas trazidas a comunidade.

Enquanto observo algumas tags a procura de perguntas que eu possa ajudar a responder, vejo algumas perguntas receberem votos negativos logo após serem postadas, a exemplo cito [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/453910/erro-de-estrutura-ao-utilizar-tab-navigation-do-react-navigation) que eu mesmo abri, ela recebeu um voto negativo enquanto possuía apenas uma visita, e tão imediatamente sua postagem que me pergunto se ha um sistema automático no stack para negativar perguntas por algum motivo.

Aproveito o espaço para questionar a viabilidade de exigir a adição de um comentário a pergunta ao negativa-la quando esta for a primeira negativa e feita a um usuário iniciante (não aplicando-se ao meu usuário). E sugerir um comentário quando for a primeira negativa a um usuário mais experiente (como o meu usuário).

Grato a todos, e na expectativa de ver votos negativos a essa pergunta (risos)...

Comment: Infelizmente isso é quase que padrão no SO, downVote e sem justificativa, sugiro que leia isso https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8295/campanha-postar-coment%c3%a1rios-ao-dar-votos-negativos-ou-de-fechamento-ven%c3%a7a-o-de não que vá adiantar alguma coisa... E prefiro votar para fechar do que dar um downvote, normalmente que da downvote não volta para remover o voto depois que a autor arruma a pergunta, e votando para fechar pelo menos o autor da pergunta vai ter uma dica de onde melhorar

Comment: Não existe sistema automático que negativa perguntas/respostas. Quanto a exigir comentário ao votar, já foi sugerido várias e várias vezes, não só aqui no [pt.so], mas em praticamente [todos os sites da rede](https://stackexchange.com/sites) e sempre foi negado, tanto que existe [um FAQ específico](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325416/401803) só pra isso (eu sugiro que leia - mesmo que vc não concorde, é interessante para entender o raciocício da empresa para ser assim e porque provavelmente "nunca" farão isso)

Comment: Neste link é tratado de praticamente tudo que pode dar problema em perguntas: [Guia de Sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Comment: Não adianta votar e justificar. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/459145/d%c3%bavida-loop-infinito os usuários em maioria levam para o lado pessoal e se tornam incapazes de editar a própria pergunta para melhorar e passam a contestar os negativos nos comentários. É traumático.